# How to print arrays inside array by Laravel blade?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, treeview, laravel-blade

My function returns an array to a variable in laravel blade page like this :

```php
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Enterpise
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => name1
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 5
                                    [name] => name2
                                    [children] => 
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 6
                                    [name] => name3
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 11
                                                    [name] => name4
                                                    [children] => 
                                                )

                                                               .....
```

Now I want to print these values inside my page by using something like `foreach`. Consider that their children's numbers are not specified, it is impossible to do that inside of my function. It is important to me to be done in blade. How can I do that?

Answer (score 20):

In your blade files you can use any php functions like `print_r()`.

**Example:**

```
{{ print_r($array) }}
```

Comment: dd() is generic function provided by laravel you can use just like native php function in blade.  {{ dd($array) }} https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-dd-gets-upgrade.

Answer (score 6):

As this is very old issue but I found `json` directive very useful.

```
<pre>
    <code>
        @json($array);
    </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the way for your problem over here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/passing-arrays-to-blade-and-iterating

Or you can use:
{{ echo json_encode($yourarray) }}

but this will print your array as json encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP directive

```
@php
 echo "<pre>";
   print_r($array);
 echo "</pre>";
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this clean and simple solution that outputs your array in a nicely formatted way, using JSON:

```
<pre><code>{{ json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) }}</code></pre>
```

You can drop the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` if you want it displayed on a single line:

```
<pre><code>{{ json_encode($array) }}</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best output and less code has print_r() :

```
<pre>
    {{print_r($array)}}
</pre>
```